# Web Parser : Stuck In Infinite While Loop(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, python-requests, social-networking

I Wrote Following Program :

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import requests
import json
import time

final_data = []

# Parameters
coordinates = ['-8.705833, 115.261377']
keywords = ['restaurant']
radius = '1000'
api_key = 'acbhsjbfeur2y8r' #insert your Places API

for coordinate in coordinates:
    for keyword in keywords:
        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+coordinate+'&radius='+str(radius)+'&keyword='+str(keyword)+'&key='+str(api_key)
        
    while True:
        print(url)
        respon = requests.get(url)
        jj = json.loads(respon.text)
        results = jj['results'] 
        for result in results:
            name = result['name']
            place_id = result ['place_id']
            lat = result['geometry']['location']['lat']
            lng = result['geometry']['location']['lng']
            rating = result['rating']
            types = result['types']
            vicinity = result['vicinity']
            data = [name, place_id, lat, lng, rating, types, vicinity]
            final_data.append(data)
        time.sleep(5)
        
        if 'next_page_token' not in jj:
                break;
        else:
            next_page_token = jj['next_page_token']
            url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key='+str(api_key)+'&pagetoken='+str(next_page_token)

labels = ['Place Name','Place ID', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Types', 'Vicinity']

export_dataframe_1_medium = pd.DataFrame.from_records(final_data, columns=labels)
export_dataframe_1_medium.to_csv('export_dataframe_1_medium.csv')
```

Basically It Open Urls , Find Relevant Keywords Query From Google Maps And Load It In CSV Data File ,
But It Is Stuck In An **Infinite Loop** And If it Is Removed Only Cols Names Are Printed , i.e Data fetched is not getting appended

Can Anyone Suggest How To Fix:)

I actually need a working code as I have to wok with it

Comment: Or else need working implementation of same

Comment: For debugging, start without the while and check if the code works as expected on the first page. Then go to the second page and check if the code is doing as expected again. If it does you can probably assume it will for most/all (can be tested with small for loop for 10 pages). Then you want to recheck your loop ending. Move to the last page and verify that it reaches the `break` statement, you can provide a helpful print. After that put it all together in the while loop again.

Comment: When while loop removed , The `final_data.append(data)` gives empty []

Comment: I actually need a woking code as I have to wok with it

Comment: I am pretty sure you can create a url that should work. Also is it correct that the `while` is at the same level as your first `for` loop? Because now your `for keyword in keywords:` will always return a single `url` with only the last keyword. Which is similar to `keywords[-1]`.

Comment: So where is the error , why stuck in infinite while loop

Comment: Show I increase Indentation Of while loop and what about respon vars